# How to save and restore a TensorFlow graph and its state in C++?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm training my model using TensorFlow in C++. Python is used only for constructing the graph. So is there a way to save and restore the graph and its state purely in C++? I know about the Python class `tf.train.Saver` but as far as I understand it does not exist in C++.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `tf.train.Saver` class currently exists only in Python, *but* (i) it is built from TensorFlow ops that you can run from C++, and (ii) it exposes the [`Saver.as_saver_def()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/state_ops.html#Saver.as_saver_def) method that lets you get a [`SaverDef` protocol buffer](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/6567e449999e8372290518f12aae2b87c45f8dca/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saver.proto) with the names of ops that you must run to save or restore a model.

In Python, you can get the names of the save and restore ops as follows:

```
saver = tf.train.Saver(...)
saver_def = saver.as_saver_def()

# The name of the tensor you must feed with a filename when saving/restoring.
print saver_def.filename_tensor_name

# The name of the target operation you must run when restoring.
print saver_def.restore_op_name

# The name of the target operation you must run when saving.
print saver_def.save_tensor_name
```

In C++ to restore from a checkpoint, you call `Session::Run()`, feeding in the name of the checkpoint file as `saver_def.filename_tensor_name`, with a target op of `saver_def.restore_op_name`. To save another checkpoint, you call `Session::Run()`, again feeding in the name of the checkpoint file as `saver_def.filename_tensor_name`, and fetching the value of `saver_def.save_tensor_name`.

Comment: Great advice! I had to remove a ":0" from the end of one string. Additionally relative paths don't work during restoring a model. Tensorcreation: `tf::Tensor string( tf::DT_STRING, tf::TensorShape( { 1, 1 } ) );`
    Feeding string: `string.matrix< std::string >()( 0, 0 ) = file_path_ + filename;`
    Execution: `TF_CHECK_OK( session_->Run( { { "save/Const:0", string } }, {}, { "save/control_dependency" }, nullptr ) );`

Comment: @Trevir , mrry: could you please post the snippet? I'm new to tensorflow and the documentation doesn't help.. I'd be extremely grateful to you!

Comment: @Surferonthefall: The former comment has all the necessary code. Use the python script to get the correct operation name, e.g. "save/Const:0". After that you can use the operation name in c++ via the session->run method.

Comment: Amazing hacky solution! Python script has to contain `saver = tf.train.Saver(...)` line. I can confirm that one has to rename "save/control_dependency:0" to "save/control_dependency"

Comment: @mrry Could you have a look at this? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/10669#issuecomment-462230580

Comment: What would be the equivalent for TF 2.0? My checkpoints saved with the C api using "save/control_dependency" operation do not load back into keras model

Answer (score 3):

The recent TensorFlow version includes some helper functions to do the same in C++ without Python. These are generate from the ProtoBuf in the pip-package (`${HOME}/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/include/tensorflow/core/protobuf/saver.pb.h`).

```
// save
tensorflow::Tensor checkpointPathTensor(tensorflow::DT_STRING, tensorflow::TensorShape());
checkpointPathTensor.scalar<std::string>()() = "some/path";
tensor_dict feed_dict = {{graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name(), checkpointPathTensor}};
status = sess->Run(feed_dict, {}, {graph_def.saver_def().save_tensor_name()}, nullptr);

// restore
tensorflow::Tensor checkpointPathTensor(tensorflow::DT_STRING, tensorflow::TensorShape());
checkpointPathTensor.scalar<std::string>()() = "some/path";
tensor_dict feed_dict = {{graph_def.saver_def().filename_tensor_name(), checkpointPathTensor}};
status = sess->Run(feed_dict, {}, {graph_def.saver_def().restore_op_name()}, nullptr);
```

This is based on the undocumented python-way ([more details](http://patwie.com/tutorials/tensorflow-cpp.html)) of restoring a model

```py
def restore(sess, metaGraph, fn):
    restore_op_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().restore_op_name   # u'save/restore_all'
    restore_op = tf.get_default_graph().get_operation_by_name(restore_op_name)
    filename_tensor_name = metaGraph.as_saver_def().filename_tensor_name  # u'save/Const'
    sess.run(restore_op, {filename_tensor_name: fn})
```

For a working and complete [version see here](https://github.com/PatWie/tensorflow_inference/).