# Tensorflow - Create Model file for Object (face) Recognition in C++

Tags: python, c++, image-processing, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am doing research on face Recognition using tensorflow.
Can I please know how how to use the code to create model file for face recognition.

**Task (required in C++)**
I have 5 folders, each folder has 4 images of a particular person.
I would like to train the images and generate a model file from scratch.
I would then like to use the model file for recognizing one of the 5 persons.

**Steps followed**
1. https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining
**Issues**

> 1. Its in Python , but I wanted in C++
> 2. It is not training the model file from scratch

2.https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception/inception

> **Issue Resolved**
>  Model can be trained from scratch.
>   **Unresolved Issue**
>  Its in Python , but I wanted in C++

Please help me in creating the model file in C++

Comment: you want to use a model trained in Python from a C++ executable, am i right? or you want to do the training in C++?

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response I want to do the training in C++

Comment: Tutorials like this are easily googlable.

Comment: Hi there are no tutorials available for c++ for creating a model file, I googled for 2 days

Comment: https://tebesu.github.io/posts/Training-a-TensorFlow-graph-in-C++-API — just find the appropriate python tutorial and rewrite it to use C++ API. I’d suggest you start with Python just to get the model working though. It is easier than doing it in C++.

Comment: + this answer may be of help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671613/737347