# Fastest way to evaluate Tensorflow model in production environment (under C# if possible)

Tags: c#, performance, tensorflow, production, evaluation

Consider I have already trained model which is saved using `tf.train.Saver()`. Now I would like to use the model in a production environment which is in C#. I was already able to use [TensorFlowSharp](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp) and load (which is a little hack described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37671613/1815451)) the model using Saver tensors into TensorFlowSharp and execute it well.

In a batch evaluation, I get fast and quite expected performance results per case which is like 10-20 microseconds. Problem is that in the production environment the model must predict sample by sample (online usage). When calling prediction for a single vector, I get average execution time around 1 millisecond, which is much slower.

When comparing to [CNTK](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK) models, which gives evaluation execution time in microseconds even for single calls, this seems quite unfortunate.

I blame calling session.GetRunner().Run() with passing new input each time. I would like to ask if there is some way how to execute/evaluate Tensorflow graph in such environment in the fastest way possible, considering I don't know inputs ahead (so fast, online evaluation). Is this issue only related to C# wrapper? Would it help if I would use C/C++ api? Or is it a problem in the session-runner calls?

I have compiled binaries, Also compiling TFSharp for myself with allowed unsafe code.

Thank you