# How to Save and Restore a Neural Network (ClientSession) with a purly C++ API?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I would like to save a trained ClientSession (neural network) only with a C/C++ interface. (wherein I use tensorflow release 1.9 on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2017)

I found a lot of information how to do it with python, but I have to (therefore can) use only C++.
At
[How to save and restore a TensorFlow graph and its state in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508771/how-to-save-and-restore-a-tensorflow-graph-and-its-state-in-c)
I found some advice, but unfortunately I have no "overloaded function" for this example code in my release.

Basically this is my code:

```
Scope scope = Scope::NewRootScope();
...
ClientSession session(scope);
...
TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ w1, w2, w3, b1, b2, b3 }, nullptr));

for (int i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
    TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ {x, x_data}, {y, y_data} }, { loss }, &outputs));
    TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({ {x, x_data}, {y, y_data} }, { w1, w2, w3, b1, b2, b3, layer_3 }, nullptr));
}
...
// And now I would like to save the session, scope or graph such that I can use it in/on another program/function/system.
```

Thanks in advance,
Martin

Comment: What do you mean by "*but unfortunately I have no "overloaded function"*"? In the linked question, there is no mention to such thing.

Comment: Hi Acorn, thanks for replying, I tried to use the suggested "template" code from the link above. But my release has no overloaded function which fits to the code, and every "test" I made by changing the elements in the function-call didn't work. Particularly "sess->Run(" of my release seams to be different to the one discussed in the other chat.

Comment: I found that in "freeze_saved_model.cc" are functions which might be useful for me.
But this is only prepared for version higher r1.13, and I simply CAN'T create a working Windows/C++/VisualStudio solution higher than r1.9 ......

I followed precicely the instructions from https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_windows but I can't manage it to let it run.

I have seen, that in version r1.9 is a file called "freeze_saved_model_test.cc", which contains the functions I need. Has anyone an Idea how to use the test files?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I can answer my own question. I found 2 "example codes" online:
Here, one can see how to save a graph:

https://github.com/rockzhuang/tensorflow/commit/fb6a6f4e3dd6e663a14b672ab5c616d968d62bc5#diff-a46c94d7dc93c6f7a3b632dc14e46479

and here, how to restore the graph:

https://github.com/rockzhuang/tensorflow/commit/5b24dfcf7e235bbffd2d60ccf1689b4ecb06c63b

Awesome examples! It worked for me, so "the interested reader" may try it too.